# How to transform this data for logistic regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I hava 'y' and 'X' data:

`y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...]` its ok for my purpose

and

```
X = [['reg' '03b' '03e' 'buy']
 ['reg' '03b' '04e' 'sell']
 ['pref' '02b' '03e' 'sell']
 ['cur' '03b' '03e' 'buy']
 ['val' '03b' '03e' 'buy']
 ['reg' '03b' '03e' 'buy'] ...]
```

`X[0]` may take values : 'reg'/'pref'/'cur'/'val'

`X[1]` : string with number of mounth + b( = begin) at the end

`X[2]` : string with number of mounth + e( = end) at the end

`X[3]` : 'buy' or 'sell'

But I cant do

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X,y)
```

Because I have troubles with structure of X (it is lists with strings)

I want to fix it and do:

```
logreg = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
i=0
while i<len(X):
    logreg.fit(X[i])
    b[i]=logreg.transform(X[i])
    i=i+1
```

But I get this:

```
[3 0 1 2]
[3 0 1 2]
[3 0 1 2]
[3 0 1 2]
[3 0 1 2]
[3 0 1 2]
...
[3 0 1 2]
```

All elements are the same. How can I correctly transform my data for .fit(X,y)?

Comment: Can you provide the error that you get?

Comment: I add more information. I have all the same elements in transformed X and its incorrect because
['cur' '03b' '03e' 'buy'] =  ['reg' '05b' '06e' 'sell']= [3 0 1 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you mistake row and column in X.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
X = [['reg', '03b', '03e', 'buy'],
    ['reg', '03b', '04e', 'sell'],
    ['pref', '02b', '03e', 'sell'],
    ['cur', '03b', '03e', 'buy'],
    ['val', '03b', '03e', 'buy'],
    ['reg', '03b', '03e', 'buy']]
X = np.array(X)
b = np.zeros(X.shape)
logreg = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
i = 0
while i < X.shape[1]:
    logreg.fit(X[:,i])
    b[:,i] = logreg.transform(X[:,i])
    i += 1
b
array([[2., 1., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [3., 1., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: @user330959 if you find the answer helpful please check it as accepted answer to save time for others having a similar problem.